# Не работает в Spring'е mapping при вызове pdf

Tags: java, spring-mvc

В Spring проекте почему-то неправильно работает mapping. Домашняя страница отображается нормально, но при выборе получения pdf-файла появляется ошибка, что такого ресурса нет.

Файл *index.jsp*

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Microsoft Excel</a></li>
   <li><a href="/index/get">Adobe PDF</a></li>
</ul>
```

Файл *EntryController.java*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class EntryController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRasps(Model model) {        
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showListInPdf() {   
    return new ModelAndView("pdfDocument", "entryMaps", null);
}
}
```

Файл *web.xml*

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>    
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Файл *spring-servlet.xml*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.chsu.shedule.controller" />    
<mvc:annotation-driven />    
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />    
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:order="1"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="location" >
        <value>/WEB-INF/excel-pdf-config.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Файл *excel-pdf-config.xml*

```
<bean id="pdfDocument" class="com.chsu.shedule.pdf.PDFDocument" />
```

Если для проверки сделать так:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class EntryController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showListInPdf() {   
    return new ModelAndView("pdfDocument", "entryMaps", null);
}
}
```

получается на выходе pdf файл, хотя и с расширением htm.
Проект в Spring первый пробный, поэтому никак не могу найти, где ошибся.

Comment: посмотрите внимательно на свой <servlet-mapping>

Comment: Спасибо, вы были правы! <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> решило проблему